# Unable to reload datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image: 4 tabs]

If you see above image have 4 tabs Z , A , C , L all the tabs have datatable
when I click on the tab an ajax call is made on the using the below code:

```
tblMain12.columns.adjust().draw(false);
```

And the above issue happens can some please give me a hint?

The header and footer are fixed.

Below is the code that i have written but when i move from one tab to another some times all the header are aligned as shown in the image when i move fast from one tab to another the issue shown in image occurs

https://jsfiddle.net/tristevenpinto/6ht0ofe3/73/

Comment: What is the issue that is happening? footer row span issue?

Comment: Your problem could come from a number of places, so it's impossible for us to help you without additional information

Comment: thanks guys have added the sample